# Is there a way to implement asp.net authorization policies in views/front end?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have applied the asp.net authorization in my views but it seems not to apply.  I am using resource. author to display buttons on list.

```
public class IncidentAuthorizationHandler: AuthorizationHandler<SameAuthorRequirement, Incident>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                  SameAuthorRequirement requirement,
                                                   Incident resource)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity?.Name == resource.CreatedBy)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

this is the code in my view but it seems not to work

```
<td>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Select an Action
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                                   
                                    @if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "EditPolicy")).Succeeded)
                                    {
                                        <a class="dropdown-item-custom" asp-action="EditIncident" asp-controller="Incident" asp-route-Id="@i.IncidentId"><i class="fa fa-sm fa-edit text-white mr-3"></i>Edit</a>
                                    }

                                        <a class="dropdown-item-custom" asp-action="ViewIncident" asp-controller="Incident" asp-route-Id="@i.IncidentId"><i class="fa fa-sm fa-comment text-white mr-3"></i>View</a>

                                        <a class="dropdown-item-custom" asp-action="PrintIncident" asp-controller="Incident" asp-route-Id="@i.IncidentId"><i class="fa fa-sm fa-print text-white mr-3"></i>Print</a>
                                    
                                        <a class="dropdown-item-custom" asp-action="DeleteIncident" asp-controller="Incident" asp-route-Id="@i.IncidentId"><i class="fa fa-sm fa-trash text-white mr-3"></i>Delete</a>


                                    </div>
                            </div>

                        </td>
```

the user is the owner of the document but the button is not showing.  it seems it does not recognize the owner. any assistance is appreciated

the startup looks like this

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EditPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SameAuthorRequirement()));
});
```

Comment: Don't do that in the view code to begin with. The controller *is* the front end. The view is just the server-side rendering code. Views are for rendering, not calling services. Determine whether the user has authorization in the controller and just don't include that data in the model. Or set a flag on the model according to the the permissions. There's no difference between `@if (Model.IsEditor)` and `@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "EditPolicy")).Succeeded)` except the first works properly

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be solved by adding this code in your program.cs file:

```
builer.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IncidentAuthorizationHandler>();
```

For testing purpose, I followed the [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) created a project, here is my own Handler code:

```
public class MinimunAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
    {

        var userEmailClaim = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);

        var userEmail = Convert.ToString(userEmailClaim.Value);

        if (userEmail == "123@gmail.com") 
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And here is the code I added to my program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimunAgeHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>{
options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement("123@gmail.com")));});
```

Ignore the Handler's name, I followed the document and just changed the inside function. Now here is my index page's code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

@{ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>


@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "AtLeast21")).Succeeded)
{
    <p>This paragraph is displayed because you fulfilled PolicyName.</p>
}
```

At last, here is my test result:
[image]

You can see from the picture, when login as "123@gmail.com", the paragraph will be shown.